# Centering a checkbox

Tags: html, checkbox, centering

I can't completely (only the label is centered when I try) center [this checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMVIR.png) to my 'card', how can I do it ?

I tried `<center>...</center>` and other CSS found on Stack Overflow but no one I found are working, so I ask help here.

Source : http://byrushan.com/projects/ma/1-6-1/jquery/dark/form-examples.html

Code :

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="">
        <i class="input-helper"></i>
        Don't forget to check me out
    </label>
</div>
```

Current CSS : https://hastebin.com/aqelapodiy.css

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the relevant source code in your question. Many people will not click/open unknown links.

Comment: Hello @NewToJS and thank you. I did it.

Comment: Add `text-align:center;` to your `.checkbox` div styles? [**JsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xjbcs36/)

Comment: @NewToJS This is not working for me, only the label is centered. http://prntscr.com/h30rxz

Answer (score 0):

```html
<center>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="">
        <i class="input-helper"></i>
        Don't forget to check me out
    </label>
</div>
</center>
```

Works absolutely fine, maybe some other css that you are adding is hindering with the center tag

Comment: This is not working for me, only the label is centered. http://prntscr.com/h30rxz

Comment: @JoannaForest I am telling you. You are adding some extra css. may be an external style sheet. either add that to the question or check that out. That must be defining the way your checkbox looks and is probably overriding things you specify over here

Comment: I added the source (template) that I'm using in my question. I tried to search in the css files but I am really bad with CSS so I can't do anything.

Comment: @JoannaForest please listen to the comments and put the code out there in the question. The viewers shouldn't have to do extra work to understand your question. If you are not  that good with css, you should spend a day working on that and then come back to this problem

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Comment: @JoannaForest you are just not getting it. There are 74 instances of the word checkbox in that file. Once again you placed a link. This is not the way to ask a good question. Narrow it down to the possible cases of that css code where it might be creating a problem and copy paste just that m uch code over here. Why would you expect someone to look at the entire code that you using and have no knowledge of?

Answer (score 0):

You can write following css in your stylesheet:

```css
.checkbox{
display:block;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="">
        <i class="input-helper"></i>
        Don't forget to check me out
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not working for me, only the label is centered. prntscr.com/h30rxz

Comment: try by adding property for input[type=checkbox]. If its also not working then add your code here.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to work and I added my codes to the question :)

Comment: That link is not accessible